# Spark AR How to rotate a target tracker

Tags: augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

Is it possible to rotate a target tracker in Spark AR? I have tried transforming it but the options are greyed out.

Also, I'm currently new to Spark AR but where can I get simple fbx models to play around with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to rotate a target tracker because it is not an object. The problem I was facing is that the texture used in the target tracker is for some reason rotated at 90 degrees with respect to the camera orientation, so the objects appearing upon the texture detection were rotated at 90 degrees as well.

THe workaround which worked for me was to rotate the objects by 90 degrees in the project; as a result, everything looks rotated at 90 degrees in the Spark AR viewport but works fine in the Spark AR Player app on the mobile.